# Facebook App Visibility to Public

Tags: facebook, sdk, visibility, public

What Facebook SDK permission should I ask to make my facebook app visible to public?

From the App User settings on the facebook page, I am unable to change Visibility of app and posts from Friends to Public.

Comment: Could you clarify as to what do you want to change, do you want the posts that your app makes as public or activity generated on app as public or something else?

Comment: First of all thank you for you reply Anvesh. I am unable to post images yet so I will give a link to an image instead to show what I am trying to achieve. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=663469653679970&l=a9ad647769 and https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=663469637013305&l=c78d6b41a9 .

Comment: What permission so my app can post publicly on the users behalf.

Comment: Speedy Uploader is one app that when you use it the first time it will ask you if you want to allow the app to post publicly on the user's behalf. That is exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: The Default Activity Privacy on the App Settings page I tried that also but I think thats just serves as an information in App Center as to what permissions are required by the app.

Comment: You can refer to this solution on a similar problem.


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733026/set-default-activity-privacy-to-public-on-app-install

Comment: I just answered this. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32390799/1159930

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can select the **Default Activity Privacy** for your app by selecting the same in your App Settings. This can be found navigating to `Settings > Permissions` in your App Settings page.

Secondly, this can be changed by the User when he is displayed with the `Login dialog` and may choose something else. So, instead on depending on it I would like you to use the `privacy` field for the [Posts](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), with the value as

```
privacy={'value':'EVERYONE'}
```

Same mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/), so that the posts gets the Public visiblility. Although just as a pointer, user may, if he doesn't likes the visibility value, change the same to something else. So, if there is something dependent on the Post been public in your system, it should be thought before hand.

Comment: If the user changed the privacy setting that is fine by me at least user knows how to put it back should the need to. I want to initially set the app visibility/privacy to public and this is so the user will not think it is not working.

Comment: By the way, to add to that, I don't have the option to set app privacy/visibility on the login page. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Has Facebook removed the 'Default Activity Privacy' section? I can't find that setting anywhere in my app's FB dashboard.