# Set Default Activity Privacy to public on app install

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, privacy

I've noticed in my last app that it installs with the Activity Privacy set to "Only me" and when the new permissions dialog shows there's no way to change the privacy from there, and this app installs with "Only me" privacy.
I wanted to force the Public value for this app privacy and I don't know how to do it.

I show the permissions dialog using PHP:

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://mytabpage'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: Set the _Default Activity Privacy_ in the app dashboard (under “Permissions”).

Comment: I did it since the beginning, and doesn't seem to affect

Answer (score 1):

The solution can be found in the bug reported [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/251254384985265/)

As Thomas says here:

> After further testing, if the user has NEVER installed the app before, it seems to follow the default activity. If the user HAS USED the app before, and removed it from their profile, when they re-add it, it uses whatever settings they had before.

Hope that helps. If you think otherwise or find any deviation from this theory let me know!